# error at logon when pressing CTRl ALT DEL

Tags: windows-xp, login, sp3

windows xp sp3

Everytime i press ctrl alt del to logon to the system, notepad pops open with some random error message filled with a bunch of gibberish i can't read, just a bunch of squares and stuff. Once in a while it says "c:\windows\system32\mui\0407\xpsp1res.dll" 
the solutions i've found where to delete the desktop.ini files in startup and a few other places, which i did, but now the error message just changes folder to \408\xpsp3res.dll

This being an error before i even get to login, how would i go about finding out whats running on bootup? I don't see anything out of place in msconfig or any weird services. Hijack this isn't helping either.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the problem?

Comment: Maybe tomorrow, can you even take a screenshot at the ctrl alt del screen?

Comment: If you can't take a screenshot in software, try using a camera to take a picture of the screen.  The quality will be lower, but at least we can see what the problem is.

Comment: sorry for the delay, here we go:
http://i51.tinypic.com/j8pni1.jpg
http://i56.tinypic.com/4rrpfo.jpg
http://i54.tinypic.com/9ftr1k.jpg

Comment: These are dialog boxes normally used to display notifications to users before logging in, as on a school or work computer.  The files you mentioned, `xpsp1res.dll` and `xpsp3res.dll`, are related to service packs.  It looks like you have some kind of problem with a system file.  Perhaps you have a problem with the SP3 update or its files?

Comment: the sp was built into the image, this system was installed a while ago. why would it go bad at random now? would sfc scannow do anything for it?

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer and do you have any recovery media?

Comment: its  a dell optiplex 760, i can reimage it if necessary, but i wanted to avoid that. If I wanted to make that dialog pop out with a custom message, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: now i've got the same issue on another computer, different set of applications. I started scanning for virus issues, but haven't seen anything yet

Comment: virus scan fixed second pc, first one still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a suitable solution to the problem, never found the cause though.

creating this key disables the popups:
Root Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
Entry: NoPopupsOnBoot
Data Type: REG_SZ

found the info here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742541.aspx

It disables all errors on bootup, No idea what other kind of errors are suppressed though.

Comment: Does it solve the problem? It looks like nasty virus to me...